# Amazon Cognito Error : Error trying to do updateUserAttributes Cognito Service (Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [A-Za-z0-9-_=.]+] )

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to do **updateUserAttributes** of **Class: AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider** bearing in mind 
***with Node js***
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#updateUserAttributes-property

```
// Set credentials
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
});
let CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

// Make the call to obtain credentials
AWS.config.credentials.get(function() {
  // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
  var token = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
  var params = {
    UserAttributes: [{
      Name: 'custom:XXXXXXXX',
      Value: 'XXXXXXXX'
    }],
    AccessToken: token
  };
  CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.updateUserAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      return callback(false, err.stack);
    }
    console.log(data);
    callback(true, data);
  });
});
```

And the response is:
***{ [InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'accessToken' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [A-Za-z0-9-_=.]+]

  message: '1 validation error detected: Value at \'accessToken\' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [A-Za-z0-9-_=.]+',

  code: 'InvalidParameterException',

  time: Thu Jun 23 2016 09:50:15 GMT-0500 (COT),

  requestId: 'cb98c60f-3951-11e6-a4c2-3d6c71f21f4c',

  statusCode: 400,

  retryable: false,

  retryDelay: 36.788223031908274 }***

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using "_" in Name or Value?

Comment: @error2007s Yes, I'm using **custom:next_token** in Name Attribute!
Why?

Comment: Yes remove that "_" and it will work

Comment: @error2007s No, I changed it and the same error. But the problem is with the token not with attributes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AccessToken` accepted by CognitoIdentityServiceProvider is not the session token from your AWS credentials. It is one of the [tokens](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html) vended by the Cognito User Pools service (Identity Provider) when you authenticate a user using username and password.

See [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-the-javascript-sdk.html) for instructions to use our Cognito User Pools JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Please accept the answer if you think this is what you needed.